# How to change font color in visual studio code december 2021 version windows 11

Tags: visual-studio

The many places I have searched lead me to the json file, but this file doesn't have variables for editor font color or brightness or changing the foreground and background colors.  The many videos I have seen show versions of VCS that did have a box color selector, but the latest VCS lacks this.  Any help is appreciated. I'd also like to add Monaco as my terminal font, but the many true-type fonts I found on the internet are rejected in my preferences box (Windows 11).
Migs